# Agora channel Connection keeps interrupted in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io, agora-implementation

I am developing a voice communication app using agora SDK. I was using version 3.7, then I needed to use extensions provided by agora (Bose PinPoint Filter), then I upgraded the agora version to 4.0( we have to use SDK version 4.0 to use extensions). But after I upgraded to 4.0.0.3 , when joined the channel it keeps calling **rtcEngineConnectionDidInterrupted(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit)** delegate. I could not find why this happens. Can anyone find a solution to the problem I am facing?